# Узнать имя процесса, которому принадлежит активное окно

Tags: c++, winapi

Как я делаю беру хендл активного окна функцией `GetForegroundWindow()`, надо по этому хендлу узнать имя процесса при помощи WinAPI.

Как это можно сделать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно просто и коротко:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <psapi.h>

int main()
{
    Sleep(1000);   // Чтобы успеть переключиться в другое окошко :)

    DWORD pid;
    GetWindowThreadProcessId(GetForegroundWindow(),&pid);
    HANDLE hProc = OpenProcess(PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION | PROCESS_VM_READ,
                               FALSE, pid);
    char name[256];
    if (GetProcessImageFileName(hProc,name,256))
        std::cout << name << std::endl;
    CloseHandle(hProc);
}

#pragma comment(lib,"user32")
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Сначала получите идентификатор процесса, которому принадлежит активное окно: [`GetWindowThreadProcessId()`](http://www.vsokovikov.narod.ru/New_MSDN_API/Window/fn_getwindowthreadprocessid.htm).
2. Затем получите описатель (дескриптор, хендл) процесса с помощью [`OpenProcess()`](http://vsokovikov.narod.ru/New_MSDN_API/Process_thread/fn_openprocess.htm). При открытии процесса достаточно указать право на `PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION` — получение ограниченной информации о процессе.
3. Наконец, извлеките по описателю имя процесса: [`GetProcessImageFileName()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/ms683217(v=vs.85).aspx).

   Данная функция доступна, начиная с Windows XP. Для более ранних версий ОС необходимо использовать [`GetModuleFilenameEx()`](http://vsokovikov.narod.ru/New_MSDN_API/PSHelper/fn_getmodulefilenameex.htm), но тогда права доступа к процессу должны быть `PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION | PROCESS_VM_READ`.

Почему я не заменил шаги 1 и 2 на вызов функции [`GetProcessHandleFromHwnd()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/dd318087(v=vs.85).aspx)? Дело в том, что эта функция пытается открыть процесс с избыточным набором привилегий, которых у пользователя может и не быть. К примеру, `PROCESS_VM_READ` (чтение чужой памяти) неприменим к процессам, запущенным не под текущим пользователем (если текущий пользователь не администратор).

Итоговый код:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <windows.h>
#include <psapi.h>

std::string getForegroundWindowProcessName()
{
    const HWND hForeground = GetForegroundWindow();
    if(hForeground)
    {
        DWORD dwPID = 0;
        GetWindowThreadProcessId(hForeground, &dwPID);
        const HANDLE hProc = OpenProcess(PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION, FALSE, dwPID);
        if(hProc)
        {
            TCHAR szPath[MAX_PATH];
            GetProcessImageFileName(hProc, szPath, sizeof(szPath));
            CloseHandle(hProc);

            // Пытаемся извлечь имя файла. Если GetProcessImageFileName по каким-то
            // причинам предоставил не путь, а просто имя, возвращаем именно его.
            TCHAR szTitle[MAX_PATH];
            if(GetFileTitle(szPath, szTitle, sizeof(szTitle)) == 0)
                return std::string(szTitle);
            else
                return std::string(szPath);
        }
        else
            // Ошибка при открытии процесса. За подробностями — к GetLastError()
            return std::string();
    }
    else
        // Ни одно окно не выделено
        return std::string();
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << getForegroundWindowProcessName();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ответ взят [отсюда](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/865152/how-can-i-get-a-process-handle-by-its-name-in-c)

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <windows.h>
#include <tlhelp32.h>

int main( int, char *[] )
{
    PROCESSENTRY32 entry;
    entry.dwSize = sizeof(PROCESSENTRY32);

    HANDLE snapshot = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS, NULL);

    if (Process32First(snapshot, &entry) == TRUE)
    {
        while (Process32Next(snapshot, &entry) == TRUE)
        {
            if (stricmp(entry.szExeFile, "target.exe") == 0)
            {  
                HANDLE hProcess = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, FALSE, entry.th32ProcessID);

                // Do stuff..

                CloseHandle(hProcess);
            }
        }
    }

    CloseHandle(snapshot);

    return 0;
}
```

Если вы хотите использовать `PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS` в открытом процессе, воспользуйтесь этим кодом.

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <windows.h>
#include <tlhelp32.h>

void EnableDebugPriv()
{
    HANDLE hToken;
    LUID luid;
    TOKEN_PRIVILEGES tkp;

    OpenProcessToken(GetCurrentProcess(), TOKEN_ADJUST_PRIVILEGES | TOKEN_QUERY, &hToken);

    LookupPrivilegeValue(NULL, SE_DEBUG_NAME, &luid);

    tkp.PrivilegeCount = 1;
    tkp.Privileges[0].Luid = luid;
    tkp.Privileges[0].Attributes = SE_PRIVILEGE_ENABLED;

    AdjustTokenPrivileges(hToken, false, &tkp, sizeof(tkp), NULL, NULL);

    CloseHandle(hToken); 
}

int main( int, char *[] )
{
    EnableDebugPriv();

    PROCESSENTRY32 entry;
    entry.dwSize = sizeof(PROCESSENTRY32);

    HANDLE snapshot = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS, NULL);

    if (Process32First(snapshot, &entry) == TRUE)
    {
        while (Process32Next(snapshot, &entry) == TRUE)
        {
            if (stricmp(entry.szExeFile, "target.exe") == 0)
            {  
                HANDLE hProcess = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, FALSE, entry.th32ProcessID);

                // Do stuff..

                CloseHandle(hProcess);
            }
        }
    }

    CloseHandle(snapshot);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Вообще-то это ищется хэндл по имени, а не имя по окну, как просили...

Comment: @Harry не так понял значит вопрос.